# dbus NetworkManager: supply "/" as DBusInterface parameter in Java

Tags: java, dbus, introspection, networkmanager

The [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.GetDevices) for activating a wireless connection with `ActivateConnection` says that you can supply `"/"` as the second and third parameters to get dbus to choose sensible defaults for you.

As the bindings for the function in Java are of type `DBusInterface`, how do you do that?  You can hardly write `(DBusInterface)"/"`, can you?

If anyone can answer the above, I will very grateful.  For anyone with a bit more time or knowledge of this area, the *real* problem I'm trying to solve is that my call to `ActivateConnection` crashes out.  Here is my code leading up to the crash.  It references [this interface](https://github.com/michaelNGV/kk-dbus-nm-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/NetworkManagerIface.java).

```
            var nmIface = (NetworkManagerIface) instance.getRemoteObject(NetworkManagerIface._NM_IFACE, NetworkManagerIface._NM_PATH, NetworkManagerIface.class);
            System.out.println("Connect:" + connMatch.getObjectPath());
            System.out.println("Adaptor:" + adaptor.getObjectPath());
            System.out.println("AccessP:" + accessMatch.getObjectPath());
            for (DBusPath devName : nmIface.GetDevices()) {
                System.out.println("   Device:" + devName.getPath());
            }
            nmIface.ActivateConnection(connMatch, adaptor, accessMatch);
```

and produces this output (colouring inserted by SO):

```
Connect:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
Adaptor:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
AccessP:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/248
   Device:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1
   Device:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
   Device:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.freedesktop.dbus.exceptions.DBusExecutionException: Failed to construct D-Bus type: Not an object exported or imported by this connection at org.freedesktop.dbus.RemoteInvocationHandler.executeRemoteMethod(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at org.freedesktop.dbus.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:228)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.ActivateConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.Wifi.activateConnection(Wifi.java:322)
```

If anyone can give any pointers about what might be wrong with *that*, I will be even more grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bindings are almost certainly wrong.  If we check the documentation for [Activate Connection](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-NetworkManager.ActivateConnection), we see that it has the following parameters:

```
ActivateConnection (IN  o connection,
                    IN  o device,
                    IN  o specific_object,
                    OUT o active_connection);
```

The 'o' in this case is telling you what this parameter type is.  The types are specified in the [DBus specification](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#basic-types), but for our purposes all that we have to know is that 'o' means that this parameter is an Object Path.  This will correspond to the type [`Path`](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java/blob/f132bba5e0262b078d226d2fff63569ebfc432a3/dbus-java/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/dbus/DBusPath.java) in dbus-java(if you are using the 2.7 bindings) or [`DBusPath`](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java/blob/f132bba5e0262b078d226d2fff63569ebfc432a3/dbus-java/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/dbus/DBusPath.java) if you're using hypfvieh's updated 3.2 bindings.

The current type is:

```
public DBusInterface ActivateConnection(DBusInterface connection, DBusInterface device, DBusInterface specific_object);
```

But given what the 'o' actually means, this should probably be:

```
public DBusInterface ActivateConnection(DBusPath connection, DBusPath device, DBusPath specific_object);
```

---

A better solution would be to to use the [`CreateInterface`](https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java/blob/d259a4837fc3ff42c84f4b937b02c98e547759e1/dbus-java-utils/src/main/java/org/freedesktop/dbus/bin/CreateInterface.java) program for dbus-java(hypfvieh's version) to take the [introspection XML](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/81bd50874b4f3f29114981021e34dff3f6b932a5/introspection) and create this class for you automatically.

Comment: I understand the sense of what you are saying and the same had occured to me, but:

* hypfvieh's org.freedesktop.dbus.utils.generator.InterfaceCodeGenerator (org.freedesktop.dbus.bin.CreateInterface is deprecated) generates o => DBusInterface
* Search GitHub for `ActivateConnection`;  its parameters are always `DBusInterface`.  There may be a certain amount of echo-chambering in that, but *always*?

I will try `DBusPath` but it's going to require some adjustment of my code.

Comment: You are probably right because in the loop of my OP (`for (DBusPath devName : nmIface.GetDevices())`) I'd originally written `for (DBusInterface devName : nmIface.GetDevices())` but got a runtime error saying DBusPath can't be cast to DBusInterface.  `GetDevices` has a return type of `ao` (array of `o`) so it seems that whatever the introspection XML has, `o` might really be `DBusPath`.

Comment: I cannot believe it but you are quite right and all those repos and code samples out there are wrong.  Both `ActivateConnection` and `AddAndActivateConnection` require `DBusPath` parameters and not `DBusInterface`;  or, to be more specific, crash if they are fed `DBusInterface` parameters but do not crash if they are fed `DBusPath` parameters.